# MATLAB @ symbol for fminunc / fmincg function

Tags: machine-learning, coursera

I am following Andrew Ng's Coursera class on machine learning, and I came across this syntax for the fminunc and fmincg functions:

`fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)),initial_theta, options);`

Specifically, it is the `@` that's confusing me. I read up on it and I still don't understand what we're doing with it here. Can someone clarify what this is doing, as well as how the `t` in the function call to lrCostFunction is related to the `@(t)` in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Sabbir helped but I was still confused. After more reading I learned that the "@(something)" identifies the input variable to the private function being created. In other words, in his example above:

```
temp = @(p) sum(p,y);
```

the temp function is expecting a value for p to be input when calling temp.

```
temp(4)
```

The value y is supplied by a globally available variable that you've already created. I actually couldn't get his example to run but when I used:

```
temp = @(p) y+p;
```

it worked as expected:

```
y = 4
temp(3)

ans = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

**@(something)** is used to call a function in MATLAB or octave.

Suppose you create a function within a code. And you set a keyword for that function.
we have a **sum(x,y)** function which takes two inputs and returns the sum.
Now you fix the value of *y*, say *y = 3*; And you want to change the value of *x* every time. You can design the inline function by following:

```
y=3
temp = @(p) sum(p,y);

ret = temp(4);  % What this will do is it will add 4 with 3 and return the answer.
```

This is used where we have to call a function multiple times and we don't want to write the arguments every time. It's a shortcut method.

In your case

```
fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)),initial_theta, options);
```

the value of t will be replaced every time with initial_theta. That is how the **fmincg** or **fminunc** functions work.